# How can I resolve the render problem in the new Android Studio version (Androidx)?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, render, androidx

I updated my Android Studio to the latest version and created a new project and added a navigation drawer but the preview is not working correctly for some layouts. There is a render problem shown. I created a new project with Androidx.

I already changed the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and tried to downgrade the API but nothing changed.

Here is the error log I get:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@682acdca at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java:-1)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)   at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)   at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)   at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:7101)   at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.drawableStateChanged   ... (AppBarLayout.java:393)   at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)`

Comment: How did you migrate to AndroidX? Through Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX?

Comment: I just updated my Studio

Comment: What? Are you saying you didn't migrate to AndroidX? Or are you saying you migrated to AndroidX _and_ updated Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I updated and migrated

Comment: Ok. Please post build.gradle files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing also same problem. Android Version 3.4.2. Cache clear doesn't solve it. Only fix is close Android Studio and restart it. It happened some times later again.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
Go through the above link and follow the procedure. Change the layouts with androidx layouts.

Comment: I already migrated. Since I am using android x i can't see the preview. Its also when I am making a new project, or the Android Studio Navigation Drawer example. I can only see the "Hello World" Layout. I get the Error Message: java.lang.ClassCastException@1f7ccbc9

Comment: Here is the style file, since I think that there is the problem:

Comment: No bro.You can see the review even using androidX. Just  clicking on migrate to androidX doesn't migrate the whole project.You need to do some work manually.suppose if you are using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout this in android.In androidX,you need to change the layout to com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.Conversions,you can check from the link I provided in the answer

Comment: But isn't weird that I am just using the Navigation Drawer sample from Android Studio and still its not showing in the preview? Shouldn't it be already all in androidx code?